# Select2 selects the first option automatically with tags = true

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select with some options and i want to avoid that the first option is the selected one, so i do the following and after that i initialize the select2:

```
<select class='form-control form-control-sm'>
  <option value='100294'>Aguacate</option>
  <option value='400172'>Bundle Editable</option>
  <option value='100291'>Bundle no Editable</option>
  <option value='100260'>Camara</option>
</select>
$('select').val([]);

$('select').select2({
    tags:true
});
```

The problem is that, for some reason when i set the select2 tag options to true, after typing 2 characters, the first value is automatically selected and i don't know why

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wolfteam20/2pwkLq6j/1/

Any help would be appreciated

Edit: I think this one is a bug in select2 
[Issue](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/5516)

Answer (score 4):

I know it's been a while, but there is a workaround for this.

Turns out that if you add an empty `<option>` to the select tag, and add a placeholder, the issue is fixed.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/edu2004eu/1g94ct2e/1/)

Comment: plus 1, Awesome. Just what I needed.